# AS3 issue with XML load

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, actionscript, load

My XML file is here: http://gabriel-atanasov.eu/stylus/ask/all.xml

My code is:

---

```
var myXML:XMLList;
var myLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

myLoader.load(new URLRequest("http://gabriel-atanasov.eu/stylus/ask/all.xml"));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    myXML = new XMLList(e.target.data);
    for (var i:int = 0; i<myXML.*.length(); i++) {
        trace("Folder number: " + (i+1) + ", Name is: " + myXML.folder[i].@name);

        for (var b:int = 0; i<myXML.folder[i].*.length(); i++) {
            trace("Item number: " + (b+1) + ", Type is: " + myXML.folder[b].*.@type);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Аnd the result in 'Output' should be something like:

Folder number: 1, Name is: PNG files
   Item number: 1, Type is: png
   Item number: 2, Type is: png
   Item number: 3, Type is: png
   Item number: 4, Type is: png
   Item number: 5, Type is: png
   Item number: 6, Type is: png
   Item number: 7, Type is: png
   Item number: 8, Type is: png
   Item number: 9, Type is: png

Folder number: 2, Name is: GIF files
   Item number: 1, Type is: gif
   Item number: 2, Type is: gif
   Item number: 3, Type is: gif
   Item number: 4, Type is: gif
   Item number: 5, Type is: gif
   Item number: 6, Type is: gif
   Item number: 7, Type is: gif
   Item number: 8, Type is: gif
   Item number: 9, Type is: gif

Folder number: 3, Name is: SWF files
   Item number: 1, Type is: swf
   Item number: 2, Type is: swf
   Item number: 3, Type is: swf
   Item number: 4, Type is: swf
   Item number: 5, Type is: swf
   Item number: 6, Type is: swf
   Item number: 7, Type is: swf
   Item number: 8, Type is: swf
   Item number: 9, Type is: swf

Comment: `for (var i:int = 0; i < 3; i++) {
 MovieClip_name = "folder_" + (i +1);
 
 var MovieClip_name:MovieClip = new addFolder_mc();
    addChild (MovieClip_name);
}` Where is problem in this code & how to fix ?

Comment: I was looking for something more along the lines of a written description of the problem, not code, but it seems fsbmain has uncovered your issue regardless.

Comment: I solved the problem with XML files but I have another problem. I can drive my this code, my goal is to make a variable change my name and make a new MovieClip, it is and code (http://puu.sh/6M4Jc.png) and on addFolder_mc that is what (http:// puu.sh/6M4QY.png), can you help me I need urgent?

Comment: If you have a different question, please ask a new question. You can always provide a link back to this question for context.

Comment: I know but i can after 20 minutes. I post but delete unawares.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake is a usage of variable `i` in the second `for loop` instead of `b`. I also made some style and performance changes in your code:

```
    function processXML(e:Event):void 
    {
        var myXML:XML = new XML(e.target.data);
        var folders:XMLList = myXML.folder;
        var len:int = folders.length();
        var folder:XML, files:XMLList, file:XML, len2:int;

        for (var i:int = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
            folder = folders[i];
            trace("Folder number: " + (i+1) + ", Name is: " + folder.@name[0]);

            files = folder.*;
            len2 = files.length();
            for (var b:int = 0; b<len2; b++) 
            {
                file = files[b];
                trace("Item number: " + (b+1) + ", Type is: " + file.@type[0]);
            }
        }
    }
```

output:

```
Folder number: 1, Name is: PNG files
Item number: 1, Type is: png
Item number: 2, Type is: png
Item number: 3, Type is: png
Item number: 4, Type is: png
Item number: 5, Type is: png
Item number: 6, Type is: png
Item number: 7, Type is: png
Item number: 8, Type is: png
Item number: 9, Type is: png
Folder number: 2, Name is: GIF files
Item number: 1, Type is: gif
Item number: 2, Type is: gif
Item number: 3, Type is: gif
Item number: 4, Type is: gif
Item number: 5, Type is: gif
Item number: 6, Type is: gif
Item number: 7, Type is: gif
Item number: 8, Type is: gif
Item number: 9, Type is: gif
Folder number: 3, Name is: SWF files
Item number: 1, Type is: swf
Item number: 2, Type is: swf
Item number: 3, Type is: swf
Item number: 4, Type is: swf
Item number: 5, Type is: swf
Item number: 6, Type is: swf
Item number: 7, Type is: swf
Item number: 8, Type is: swf
Item number: 9, Type is: swf
```